# Regular expression for git repository

Tags: regex, git

What will be proper regular expression for git repositories?

example link:
git@github.com:someone/someproject.git

so it will be like
[user]@[server]:[project].git

server can be url or ip
Project can contain some other characters than alphanumeric like '-'
I'm not sure what is the role of '/'

any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not convinced a regular expression is the best solution for parsing this syntax, although many would disagree. See https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Git accepts a large range of repository URL expressions:

```
* ssh://user@host.xz:port/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://user@host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://host.xz:port/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://user@host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://user@host.xz/~user/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://host.xz/~user/path/to/repo.git/
* ssh://user@host.xz/~/path/to/repo.git
* ssh://host.xz/~/path/to/repo.git
* user@host.xz:/path/to/repo.git/
* host.xz:/path/to/repo.git/
* user@host.xz:~user/path/to/repo.git/
* host.xz:~user/path/to/repo.git/
* user@host.xz:path/to/repo.git
* host.xz:path/to/repo.git
* rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* git://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* git://host.xz/~user/path/to/repo.git/
* http://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* https://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
* /path/to/repo.git/
* path/to/repo.git/
* ~/path/to/repo.git
* file:///path/to/repo.git/
* file://~/path/to/repo.git/
```

For an application that I wrote that requires parsing of these expressions ([YonderGit](http://jeetworks.org/yondergit)), I came up with the following (Python) regular expressions:

```
    (1) '(\w+://)(.+@)*([\w\d\.]+)(:[\d]+){0,1}/*(.*)'
    (2) 'file://(.*)'       
    (3) '(.+@)*([\w\d\.]+):(.*)'
```

For most repository URL's encountered "in the wild", I suspect (1) suffices.

Comment: This does not work with a url like git@abc.def.xyz:group/project.git

Comment: Anonymous seems to be wrong, "git@" is just an instance of "[some-user]@", so it is matched by (3).

Answer (score 58):

I'm using the following regular expression for online remote repositories:

> `((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(//)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(/)?`

[View on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/H4kRw1G0YPyBFjfm)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I came here looking for a regex statement so I didn't have to spend time on it and I found the best regex debugger ever made. Thank you.

Comment: I agree about Debuggex. Unfortunately, group 4 in the above expression doesn't cope with users other than "git".

Comment: tweak a little for javascript use: /((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([\w.@:/\-~]+)(\.git)(\/)?/

Comment: +1, but `git clone user@server:project.git`, for instance, won't be matched against the provided regex. So it seems it works fine with "github-like" URLs, but not against *all* possible Git URLs...

Comment: This regex doesn't account for git hosts with dashes in the domian name. For example, git@custom-gitlab:my-group/myrepo.git. This regex bit me when trying to run with a custom-hosted gitlab instance. 

To correct, just add the dash in the domain portion:
`((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.-]+))(:(//)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(/)?`

Answer (score 4):

FYI I make a regex for get owner and repo from github or bitbucket:

```
(?P<host>(git@|https://)([\w\.@]+)(/|:))(?P<owner>[\w,\-,\_]+)/(?P<repo>[\w,\-,\_]+)(.git){0,1}((/){0,1})
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fFggA8Uc4YYKjl34)

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can do this without regex:

```
basename https://github.com/code-co-ua/exercises-php
```

Output:

```
exercises-php
```

Answer (score 1):

Roughly

```
^[^@]+@[^:]+:[^/]+/[^.]+\.git$
```

Comment: This does not handle Gerrit's git uri's.

Answer (score 1):

```
((git@|http(s)?:\/\/)([\w\.@]+)(\/|:))([\w,\-,\_]+)\/([\w,\-,\_]+)(.git){0,1}((\/){0,1})
```

This will also give you user and repo in a seperate group.

Answer (score 0):

Git repositories can come in many shapes and sizes that look nothing like that example. See the `git-clone` man page for a full list.

Some of the more common ones include using the `http` or `git` protocols instead of SSH (or, indeed, manually specifying the `ssh://` protocol). Usernames are optional, there doesn't have to be a `/` or a `.git`, ports may be specified, etc etc.

At the moment you're basically only allowing private Github repos, or ones which happen to look like them. Is that what you want? If so, S. Mark's answer looks good!

If you want to accept any git repository, the best bet is probably to make sure it's a valid URI, and then use `git` or a git library to make sure there is a real repo accessible at that URI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]+@|http(|s)\:\/\/)([A-Za-z0-9.]+(:\d+)?)(?::|\/)([\d\/\w.-]+?)(\.git)?$/i
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const REGEXP_GIT_REPO_URI = new RegExp(/^(((https?\:\/\/)(((([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,252})\.){1,8}[a-zA-Z]{2,63})\/))|((ssh\:\/\/)?git\@)(((([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,252})\.){1,8}[a-zA-Z]{2,63})(\:)))([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{1,36})(\/)([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{1,36})((\.git)?)$/);
```

The only problem is not support IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the top comment with regex like this

```
((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(//)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(/)?
```

but it does not pass this case in Golang:
`"git@github.com/abc.gits"`

Thus for golang, you should use this regex:

```
((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(//)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(/)?$
```