# How to verify valid format of URL as a git repo?

Tags: git

I do NOT want to check if the remote repository exists.  I just want to test a string and return true if the string is in the valid format for a git repo.

I'm writing a groovy script and wish to do a quick check if a string represents a valid possible git repo.

For instance if the following strings are entered the test should return true:

```
http://example.com/my-project.git
file:///absolute/path/to/my-project.git
ssh:user@example.com:my-project
my-project
```

The following strings should fail the test and cause false to be returned:

```
fil://example.com/my-project.git
ssh:user|example.com:my-project
```

I'm hoping there is a git command that can do this quick test for me and I can call git from the groovy script.  I say this because I'd like to use whatever is compiled into git to do the test as opposed to re-implementing the regular expression (or parser) that already exists in git.  If I try the latter then inevitably I'll miss something.

Comment: Is there a reason attempting to clone the repo and handling the error if it fails wouldn't work? It seems like trying to figure out how to write a regex pattern to match all the possible forms of git repos is unnecessary and overly complex.

Comment: It does not look like git does strict url validation on entry. fil:// returns error that it can't find remote helper for "fil" and "ssh:user|example..." works just fine until error with "could not read...". In your case I'd search for URL details in git documentation and try parsing them yourself. For http url: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt

Comment: @DouglasAdams, I agree! It wasn't my decision to require this check.  The folks over at Prezi decided checking the URL would enable supporting a feature in their tool called "Pride".  But they did not support all possible URLs and I want to use an URL they don't support.  So I'm looking to modify their code to support all valid git repo URLs.  The solution I finally used is in my answer below and will have to do.

Comment: Yes, there's a reason not to attempt cloning the repo and handling the error if it doesn't exist. The string might be user submitted and be something like `https://foo/bar ; rm -rf /etc ; #` so if you execute the command `git ls $url` then your system is dead. Or so on.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Regular expression for git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2514859/3744182).

Comment: ℹ️ For actually checking that the repository exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914896/check-that-git-repository-exists/69303006#69303006

Answer (score 15):

It does seem that there is no way to accomplish this with git.  The solution I finally used is

```
git ls-remote the-url-to-test
```

This returns zero on success and non-zero otherwise.  This doesn't satisfy my original question since I don't want to check if the repo exists and is valid... but it does satisfy that the URL is valid if the repo also exists.

This will have to do for my current script.

Comment: Note that this tests that a repository is accessible, which means (1) it exists and (2) you have permissions to read it. This method would give false negatives if either of those conditions are not true, which makes it a poor choice for URI validation. It's also an expensive operation since it does a network request.

Comment: @Dennis it may be a little more useful to use --exit-code option.

Comment: `git ls-remote the-url-to-test HEAD` to limit the output when the remote has many refs. If `HEAD` does not exists, it pritns nothings end the exist code is `0`, too.

Answer (score 4):

This gets close to [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address), in that you'll be able to detect some errors but not all. Given that you'll have to cope with failure anyway (wrong hostnames, bad SSH credentials), you're basically putting a few heuristics in place to catch common errors. I don't believe there's any validation code you can borrow from Git for this, although the list of URL formats ([Git URLs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a)) should be helpful in implementing this yourself.

Comment: Yet, there is https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/test-urlmatch-normalization.c and its associated https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t0110-urlmatch-normalization.sh

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]+@|http(|s)\:\/\/)([A-Za-z0-9.]+(:\d+)?)(?::|\/)([\d\/\w.-]+?)(\.git)?$/i
```

Comment: That's an ok regex, however it doesn't work for one usecase of bitbucket link and has suffix `.git` as optional - I think it should be required for `.git` to happen exactly once. I have posted an answer with the regex improved in this matter

Answer (score 4):

I've improved answer by Љубиша Ивановић and created a regex that:

- works for url valid for bitbucket, with `https` and `@`, such as `https://username@bitbucket.org/otherusername/reponame.git`
- requires the suffix `.git` to happen exactly once.

The regex:

```
/^(([A-Za-z0-9]+@|http(|s)\:\/\/)|(http(|s)\:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9]+@))([A-Za-z0-9.]+(:\d+)?)(?::|\/)([\d\/\w.-]+?)(\.git){1}$/i
```

Here you may see how the regex works, with test cases: https://regexr.com/59nrk

Comment: There is no requirement for Git URLs to have a `.git` suffix. Azure DevOps repos do not use a `.git` suffix.