# Making regex to work with sed to catch git repo name

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to use the following awesome regex with sed:

```
((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(//)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(/)?
```

It's from a previous [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514859/regular-expression-for-git-repository). I even tried a [third-party tool](http://dwaves.de/tools/escape/) to escape it properly, but without any progress. I'm trying to run:

```
sed -r 's/((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(//)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(/)?/ /g'
```

But I get an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unknown option to `s'
```

as I understand the error is due to not escaping the `\`, so I use:

```
's/((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([\w\.@\:/\-~]+)(\.git)(\/)?/ /g'
```

But it does not catch the URL. I'm trying to catch `project_14` in:

```
https://gitlab.com/test/project_14.git
```

I need to use the above regex because I need to catch the repo name from any valid Git Repo. How can I fix the regex and catch `project_14`?

Comment: Do you have to use bash? Can you use a more high level language, such as Python?

Comment: unfortunately, I have to use Bash. I wish I could use Perl/Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand your regex by breaking it down

```
(
    (git|ssh|http(s)?) # the protocol
    |
    (git@[\w.]+) # git@ and at least a letter or a dot
)
(:(//)?) # : and an optional double slash
([\w.@\:/-~]+) # This should match the repository: at least one letter, @, colon, etc. 
(.git) # .git
(/)? # an optional trailing backslash
```

A first observation is that you could remove most of the groupings.
A second observation is that you are matching everything between `://` and `.git`

A solution then could be simply:

```sh
echo https://gitlab.com/pds-test/project_14.git |sed -r 's/((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\.git)(\/)?/\8/'
project_14
```

That is, adding `\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` just before the part that matches the `.git`. For some reason, `[\w]` does not work.
You will need to update it to support all the possible git URLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo https://gitlab.com/pds-test/project_14.git | sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)\.git/\1/'
project_14
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need that exact regex. I have to catch the repo name from **every** valid git URL. So, unfortunately, it does not help much.

Comment: @vesii, show me a git url that it doesn't work with.

Comment: Adam, it accepts a superset of correct URLs, i wonder if it is relevant for Vesii.

Comment: @AdamvonNieda https://gitlab.com/pds-test/project_14/.git would be a valid Git URL (`git-clone`’s output starts with `Cloning into 'project_14'`), but your snippet doesn’t work with it.